# Using feedparser/RSS, how do I pass the feed object from views.py to .html in django?

Tags: python, django, feedparser

I am trying to add a simple RSS parser to my web application. The objective is to grab an RSS channel and display news from it on a single page. I managed to do this for a single object, but can't do it for many objects (say, 10).

The project assumes I have the files `views.py` and `RSS.html`.

The following IS code which is working for one single parse object.

`views.py`:

```
import feedparser

def rss(request):
    feeds = feedparser.parse("https://www.informationweek.com/rss_simple.asp")
    entry = feeds.entries[0]
    return render(
        request,
        'posts/rss.html',
        feeds={
            'title': entry.title,
            'published': entry.published,
            'summary': entry.summary,
            'link': entry.link,
            'image':entry.media_content[0]['url']
        }
    )
```

`RSS.html`:

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<i>Date: {{ published }}<p></i>
<b>Summary:</b><p> {{ summary }}<p>
<b>Link:</b><a href="{{ link }}"> {{ link }}</a><p>
<b>Image:</b><p><img src="{{ image }}"></img><p>
```

I don't understand how to pass all feeds into RSS.html.

I try to pass it through views and it doesn't work.

The following is code that does NOT work:

`views.py`:

```
return render(request, 'posts/rss.html', feeds)
```

`RSS.html`

```
{% for entry in feeds %}
    <li><a href="{{entry.link}}">{{entry.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing the feed object into the template, you have to loop over the `entries` field of the feed object:

Python:

```
import feedparser

def rss(request):
    feed = feedparser.parse("https://www.informationweek.com/rss_simple.asp")
    return render(request, 'posts/rss.html', {'feed': feed})
```

HTML:

```
{% for entry in feed.entries %}
    <li><a href="{{entry.link}}">{{entry.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

General documentation:

- https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference.html

The entries documentation:

- https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry.html

> A list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains data from a different entry. Entries are listed in the order in which they appear in the original feed.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but still it returns error:
'''
Django Version:  2.1.3
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'feed'
'''

Comment: @PirrenCode I mixed up the syntax between Django and Flask. Please use `{'feed': feed}` instead of `feed=feed`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks you very much, Andre! Huge like from me! It works now!